# Random time between given hours using epoch time format

Tags: python, time, epoch

I would like to have a random time from given hours range, using epoch time format.
For example, I have this:

```
start_time = int(time.time())
end_time = start_time + 5184000    # 60 days
random_time = random.randint(start_time, end_time)
```

And I want to get random time from 9am to 9pm only. What is the simplest and nicest way to achieve this in Python?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get a list of 60 days (the range is given from context) of random minutes from 9am to 9pm?

Comment: Let's say, yes. Actually, I want 3 random times per day.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood OP right, this will get 3 random times for the next 60 days and each random time is between 9am and 9pm.

```
import datetime
import random

d = datetime.datetime.today()
d = d.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

for days in range(60):
    for c in range(3): # OP wanted 3 times per date
        hours = random.randint(9, 20)
        minutes = random.randint(0, 59)
        seconds = random.randint(0, 60)

        new_d = d + datetime.timedelta(days=days, hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)

        print(new_d)
```

The reason I'm using the built-in package `datetime` and do not use the epoch time is because the epoch time cannot give any information on the actual time of the day because of leap days, minutes and seconds. But the package is built-in so this should not be a problem.

Comment: The random times may repeat in your code. Also, perhaps `seconds = random.randint(0, 59)` (`randrange(60)`) should be used. You could replace the three `random` calls with a single one `d = d.replace(hour=9, ...)` and `random_d  = d + timedelta(seconds=random.randrange(12*3600))` (assuming `9pm` is not included) .

Answer (score 1):

Struct time is read only, so cannot be hacked. If random time does not fit, just randomly tweak the hour.

```
import time,random

start_time = int(time.time())
end_time = start_time + 5184000    # 60 days

random_time = random.randint(start_time, end_time)

ts = time.localtime(random_time)
if 9 <= ts.tm_hour < 21:
   pass
else:
   hour = random.randrange(9,21)    
   rts=[ts.tm_year,ts.tm_mon,ts.tm_mday,hour,ts.tm_min,ts.tm_sec,ts.tm_wday,ts.tm_yday,ts.tm_isdst]
   random_time = time.mktime(rts)

print(random_time,time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S",rts))
```

Comment: it can produce the time earlier than `start_time`.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q:** Do you mean you want to get a list of 60 days (the range is given from context) of random minutes from 9am to 9pm?
>   **A:**
>   Let's say, yes. Actually, I want 3 random times per day.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
import time

HOUR = 3600
DAY = 24 * HOUR

def random_times(ndays=60, n_per_day=3):
    midnight = (int(time.time()) // DAY) * DAY
    start = midnight + 9 * HOUR # 9am in UTC
    end = start + ndays * DAY
    while start < end:
        yield sorted(random.sample(range(start, start + 12 * HOUR), n_per_day))
        start += DAY
```

It produces time in "epoch time format". It may produce a random time that is earlier than the current time. If it is not desirable, you could compute the random times for the very first day using a different formula:

```
available_times = range(max(int(time.time()), start), start + 12 * HOUR)
yield sorted(random.sample(available_times, min(n_per_day, len(available_times)))
```

It tries to produce `n_per_day` random times even if there are less available hours on the first day.

If you need times between 9am to 9pm in the local timezone than `start` should be calculated differently:

```
start = time.mktime(time.localtime()[:3] + (9, 0, 0) + (-1,)*3)
```

The rest is exactly the same assuming there is no DST transitions between 9am to 9pm (a reasonable assumption) or missing days (it rarely happens) in the next 60 days in the local time zone.